# Rails 4: create a scope in User model for Users with no role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, rolify

Im usung Rolify gem, I need to get all the users with no role in my app. How to create a scope in the User model that gets all the users with no role?

`User.with_no_role`

Comment: How are your `role`s are defined? `belongs_to :role`, `has_many :roles` ?

Comment: Also what is your version of rails?

Comment: Im using rolify and Im using Rails 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
User.with_role(nil)
```

Comment: Im using Rolify gem for roles, it does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `User` model, you can define your scope:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_no_role, -> { where(role: nil) }
end
```

[EDIT] As you are using Rolify, you need to do something like this:

```
User.where.not(id: User.with_role(:admin).pluck(users: :id))
```

See [here](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/issues/213)